# Htaccess redirect query string + force redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is the deal I got this string with 2 OPTIONAL parameters

```
/index.php?lang=en&p=about
```

it could be both ways

```
/index.php?p=about&lang=bg
```

and the `p` parameter is optional it could go without the `p` or the `lang` one

So far  I was able to redirect one of them from **(1)**`/index.php?p=about` to **(2)**`/about`what it does not do and I could only force it the other way around is to redirect the **(1)** to **(2)**.
When you type **(1)** to redirect you to **(2)**. I did it in reverse using [R] ..

I am really bald in this htaccess patterns and stuff, so the harder question is about the 2nd query `lang` as your presume it's about changing the language so I gotta make it like

From `/index.php?lang=en&p=about` to `/en/about`, but also the `/index.php?p=about&lang=en` to lead to `/en/about` and those redirects to be forced  when you type the whole query to be redirected to the seo friendly version.

Also when you don't have `lang` one it should go for the default `en`

I am testing right now various sample redirects, but so far nothing is working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule that will support query parameters in any order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     (?:^|&)lang=([^&]*)
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)::(?:|.*&)p=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /%1/%2? [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This redirects to non existent page, could you give me a hint how to use this query string with the 2 parameters as optional ? And this doesn't remove the query it becomes '/en/about?&lang=en&p=about'

Comment: Did you not see `/en/about` in browser after redirection? Also see my updated answer with full .htaccess

Comment: Works fine, thanks. I noticed there is a problem when I enter only language query /en/ wasn't there are an way how to check the query string (en|es) ? I noticed when I was reading about some htaccess tricks.

Comment: This answer assumes that both query parameters are present in the URL in any order.